# Visible=False on Panel of another ascx control

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

On my test.aspx page more than one asp:panels appear on different ascx controls. I want to disable a panel during runtime through the panel which I have access to. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know id of the panel you want to disable you can can do: Panel pnl = this.Page.FindControl(id) as Panel; pnl.Visible = true/false;

If the panel is not a child of the page you can write a recursive findcontrol Method.

Comment: It will work probably, but it violates the rules of oop and the reusablilty.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a method in your ascx control to enabled/disabled the panel. The parent should not have access to the panel. The ascx control must handle it.

Update:

You could create a proxy property, which passes a value to a child control (Panel1). This code is placed withing the ascx control.

```
    public bool PanelVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return Panel1.Visible;
        }
        set
        {
            Panel1.Visible = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer. Could you please give me an example?